# Unable to open pandas python package from Azure Data Studio, while configuring SQL Server 2019 Big Data Cluster

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, azure-data-studio, sql-bdc

I'm working on setting up SQL Server 2019 Big Data Cluster. One of the initial steps is installing python package: panda.

Post installation, when I try to import the package, I get the following exception in Azure Data Studio.

> import pandas
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

[image]

I don't get this exception, when I load the package from command-prompt/python.
This could be related to PATH environment variable; Or, may be a setting in Azure data studio.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Before importing pandas, try `!pip install pandas` (with the exclamation mark at the beginning), then import it.

Comment: @PauloMarques Thank you. I tried the command. No change. Same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering a bit, I found the fix. The python path needs to be added at the following location in ADS. That did the trick!

[image]